# Popup with text with file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I would like to give my users a little heads up when they try to upload a file. The text I want to show will have some infotmation and rules about the uploaded picture.

Is there a possibility for the following case:

- User clicks on "Choose File"
- Popup gives information
- User clicks on "Next" button and selects a file
- File is uploaded

The file handling will be done in PHP and JavaScript.

Maybe jQuery has a plugin for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -> jquery.fileuploadmulti.min file

For more check here -> http://hayageek.com/jquery-multiple-file-upload/

For demo -> http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/jquery-multiple-file-upload/index.php

And use jQuery UI popup for handling file upload.

In short use that Ajax Upload plugin and initialize it like

```
var settings = {
    url: "YOUR_MULTIPE_FILE_UPLOAD_URL",
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
    fileName: "myfile",
    multiple: true,
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        alert("Upload success");
    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    {       
        alert("Upload Failed");
    }
}
 
$("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Dialog module from jQuery UI. In this dialog, you could embed the form with the file upload.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

You could use jQuery to show the first and the second page. The two pages could be divs hidden somewhere in your document.